# useQuery vs client.readQuery for local state management

Tags: apollo-client

We can use Apollo cache for local state mgmt. My question is *what are the advantages & disadvantages* of using something like:

```js
const {data: {todos}} = useQuery (GET_TODOS)
```

and

```js
const client = useApolloClient ()
const {todos} = client.readQuery (GET_TODOS)
```

From my early experimentation, it seems the second version also gets rerendered for data updates. Therefore the only semantic difference I see is that `useQuery` can be customized with options. Is there anything else? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`client.query` aka `useQuery` is used to perform a query to fetch data from the server in Apollo Client. It sends a request to the server regardless of whether the data exists in the cache or not, making a network call to retrieve fresh data each time it's invoked.

On the other hand, `readQuery` is a method that reads data directly from the Apollo Client cache without making a network request. It's useful when you want to access data that has already been fetched and stored in the local cache, providing instantaneous access to that data.

Use `client.query` when you specifically need to fetch the most up-to-date data from the server, even if it might already exist in the cache. Use `readQuery` when you want to access data that has already been loaded into the cache without making an additional network request, optimizing performance by avoiding unnecessary server calls for already available data.